# Moving Entire Application from React Native 59.8 to 60+

Tags: react-native

I need to move all the source and sdk and all the dependency from react-native:59.8 to react-native: 60+. Can you give me some instruction to maintain the same application name & package name and bundle id and other things.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of 2 things:

1. Upgrade your project to RN 60+. Unfortunately it will take a little bit of work. You can check out a great guide here: https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.59.8&to=0.60.0
2. Create a new RN project, copy your `src` folder, run `yarn install && cd ios && pod install` and hope for the best :)

Comment: Hi p-sysche,

I tried but I need to maintain the same package name and application name for firebase integration. Can you tell me how to do that?